# Conversion of an image to a geotiff using R

Tags: r, geotiff, spatstat

I started out with a shape file of points data. I then converted this format to ppp format to use some spatstat functions.

The code to do this is listed below:

```
sp_points_df_al <- rgdal::readOGR(dsn = shape_path, layer = "aland_points")
# convert the spatial points data.frame to just plain ol spatial points
sp_points_al <- as(sp_points_df_al, "SpatialPoints")
# now convert the spatial points to ppp 
ppp_al <- as(sp_points_al, "ppp")
# estimate the window from the points data
wind_rr <- spatstat::ripras(ppp_al)
ppp_al_constr <- spatstat::ppp(ppp_al$x, ppp_al$y, window = wind_rr)
```

I then wanted to do some point-pattern analysis and so used the following spatstat function:

```
image <- spatstat::density.ppp(ppp_al_constr, sigma = 0.004, dimyx=c(512, 512))
```

I then display the image using the following:

```
bias_palette <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "magenta", "red", "yellow", "white"), bias=2, space="Lab")
spatstat::plot.im(k, col=bias_palette(256), ribbon = FALSE)
```

What I want to do next is create a Geotiff image from the above.  I want to do this as I want to overlay the tiff image on top of some vector data.

My question is:

How do I convert the image above into a Geotiff format...?

Comment: Can't test this on your code, but this link might help http://neondataskills.org/R/Image-Raster-Data-In-R/

Answer (score 1):

The result of `spatstat::density.ppp` is an object of class `im`. If you do `as.matrix` of this object, you get a matrix containing the pixel entries. You can then convert this to any other type of image. Also `as.data.frame(Frame(..))` of the image object will retrieve the bounding box.

Or, go to the `maptools` package, which handles `spatstat` objects, and look for a function to convert a `spatstat` class `im` object to the desired class.